# Convert string in variable lower case

Tags: bash

Using bash version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)

How can I 're-assign' or 'change' the existing value read into a variable.

If the user inputs the string `IAmString`, I'd like `propInput` to store the value `iamstring`. I'm simply printing to the console just for example sake.

```
read userInput
echo ${userInput} | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should store the output of your commands :

```
read userInput
userInput=$(echo "$userInput" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
```

Comment: you're right.  he was indeed missing the part where he sets the variable. for some reason, i thought he didn't need that part and had issues converting to lowercase...

Answer (score -1):

Ii'm surprised that doesn't already work...

Did you have trouble storing the value?

If so, you'd have to:

```
userInput=$(echo ${userInput} | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
```

But it looks like a mac environment. What results are you getting?

Edit, added `userInput=$()` and restructured to better inquire.

Comment: No, it works. But he doesn't want to have it in console. He wants to store the new string in `userInput`.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: it wasn't an answer, because i wasn't quite sure about the question.  but i GUESS i see the question now?  i still only now GUESS... that this was missing `userInput=$()`. Editing my "comment" now...